# PDFView: allow vertical scrolling till the last line becomes the top one

Tags: org-link, pdf-tools

I would like be able to link from an `org` buffer to a precise place in the PDF. When such a link is clicked, the PDF would be opened in a `PDFView` buffer on the required page and vertically scrolled so that the required line is the top one. The problem is that the `PDFView` buffer does not scroll if the last line already fits in the window, but goes to the next page. Is there a way to allow scrolling as far as making the last line the top one?

Answer (score 1):

You can scroll the window using `set-window-vscroll`,  but `image-mode` (the package pdf-view uses to display the page) will reset it soon after.  Also, Emacs may just ignore your request, if the image is not larger than the window.   So, it does not look good.